# DisplayActionSheet() doesn't put the destruction button at the top in Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, modal-dialog

I have the following code

```
string actCancel = "Cancel";
string actDelete = "Delete it";
string actRename = "Rename it";
string action = await DisplayActionSheet($"What do you want to do? \n {pickerSystem.SelectedItem}", actCancel, actDelete, actRename);
```

I expected the display to look pretty much like the second example under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups **Guide users through tasks**. But it does not, it looks like [image].

The user's choices are kind of scattered and not in a neat stack like the documentation example. Am I doing something wrong or are my expectations wrong? (VS2019 Windows, Android Pixel2 simulator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have provided one action only which is `actRename` to [params string[] buttons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.displayactionsheet?view=xamarin-forms#parameters) parameter, in your code you have assigned `actDelete` to `destruction` parameter.

You need to specify the parameter `destruction` to null is you are not using it:

```
string actCancel = "Cancel";
string actDelete = "Delete it";
string actRename = "Rename it";
string action = await DisplayActionSheet($"What do you want to do? \n {pickerSystem.SelectedItem}",
                                        actCancel, null, actDelete, actRename);
```

Here is the [`DisplayActionSheet()` API definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.displayactionsheet?view=xamarin-forms)

---

**Edit**

Xamarin.Forms is using Native Android dialog for `DisplayActionSheet()`, [here is the code responsible to create the destruction Button](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/3e7bf8dc55177c1cefd0375b0ee18d643d300c90/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/PopupManager.cs#L103-L104), as you can see it is just mapping it to the native "negative button" of the dialog using [SetNegativeButton()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder#setNegativeButton(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)).

Native Android dialogs have a layout described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#AlertDialog) and [Material ones here](https://material.io/components/dialogs)

[image]

The "negative button" is on the left besides the "positive button".

So to achieve something like the screenshot in the link you attached you probably need to create a custom native Popup.

---

**UPDATE**

The confusing screenshot in the documentation has been updated:

Issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs/issues/3253#event-4401694274

Updated page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups#guide-users-through-tasks

Comment: Unless I am missing something, my code is exactly like the doc example. "Delete" is my third parameter and I want it to appear just like "Delete" in the output in the doc.

Comment: Sorry. Hit Enter too soon. Yes, that is a help. Delete and Rename are now in the "stack." But it still does not look like the sample output. And as I say above, my original code was just like the doc. In the example "Delete" is the third parameter and it appears in the stack along with the other choices. That's what I wanted. I can live with this, but I would rather have it behave as documented.

Comment: thanks, can live with it. Not worth creating the custom control. Just (1) disappointed because the doc set my expectations, and the implementation does not meet it; and (2) wasted a bunch of my time and some of yours as a result because I thought I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Sorry to hear about that, totally agree this could be misleading and disappointing.

Comment: Delete for destruction sounds right, or what does desctruction do?